# How to specify a particular Azure Cosmos Db region replica when creating a data source in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

We plan on using Azure Cosmos Db as a data source for our indexers in Azure Search. Given the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#request-body-syntax it seems like there is no way to specify a particular Cosmos Db region as a data source. Is there no way around that? Or a way to specify it at the indexer level?

In our case we are using the geo replication in Cosmos Db, so our data is available in different regions. We would like to specify the closest region for our data sources. Or is Azure Search smart enough to reach for the closest available replica?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - there's no way to connect to a particular replica, but Cosmos Db SDK that Azure Search uses will route to the closest replica automatically.